# Particle Nodes Documentation (2.90 beta)

Tags: node-editor, particles

I have been experimenting with the new particle nodes experimental feature set in the Blender 2.90 beta, but as there don't seem to be any tutorials out yet I'm having some difficulty getting into them. What few videos that do seem to exist seem to reference certain attributes and such that are not immediately obvious in the node editor, suggesting the presence of documentation or something like it. (I've not been able to find this, however.) Many things seem to work very differently from the other node editors, and new node input/output types abound.

I know the feature is currently a work in progress and incomplete. However, would somebody mind sharing the basics of how to use particle nodes? How does it function? What are the new node types? Preexisting attributes? How does the connection system work? What are events, forces, and the like? Is the functionality between 2.90 and 2.91 currently the same? etc.

Thanks in advance!

(A link to documentation would also be nice, if it exists, though that is somewhat tangential for this question.)

Comment: That functionality (enabled in Preferences/Developer Extras then in Experimental enable 'New Particle System') is really a work in progress and has no practical value at the moment. Many of the options in the new particle node editor are labelled 'mockup' indicating they're just placeholders for what is to come. The best you can do for now is watch that space in the upcoming releases and see how it takes shape. It's certainly far too early to be of any practical use and is no doubt subject to drastically change.